# Choose between PX and Percentile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to BootStrap, I have the following question running in my mind.

1. What is the suggested way to use between px and percentiles in bootstrap??
2. Will there be any effect in website view if I used PX?

Comment: Bootstrap is a fluid responsive grid. Pixels are not.

Comment: Why are you CamelCasing the name like that? It's just "Bootstrap".

Comment: Not "percentiles", but "percentages".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a pretty significant difference between pixel units and percentile units. Percentiles are by definition variable dimensions based on the size of the container, while sizes declared in pixel units are going to always take up the given number of pixels.

You need to choose based on what you're trying to accomplish:

- do you need the rendered size to always be a fixed number of pixels? then pick pixels (or another fixed unit) (*this is not responsive*)
- do you want the rendered size to change based on the dimensions of the container? then choose percentiles

The best way to learn the difference is to experiment with both. And change the size of your browser's window.

```html
<div style="width: 80%; border: 2px solid #000; height: 30px">
  <span>80% WIDE DIV</span>
</div>
  
<div style="width: 40%; border: 1px solid #00F; height: 30px; float: left;">
  <span>60% WIDE DIV</span>
</div>
<div style="width: 40%; border: 1px solid #F00; height: 30px; float: left;">
  <span>40% WIDE DIV</span>
</div>  
<div style="clear:both; margin-bottom: 20px;"></div>

<p>FIXED LAYOUT</p>
<div style="width: 300px; border: 2px solid #000; height: 30px">
  <span>300px WIDE DIV</span>
</div>
  
<div style="width: 160px; border: 1px solid #00F; height: 30px; float: left;">
  <span>160px WIDE DIV</span>
</div>
<div style="width: 140px; border: 1px solid #F00; height: 30px; float: left;">
  <span>140px WIDE DIV</span>
</div>  
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: wonder what nut downvoted a correct answer. In responsive design, especially if the framework uses percentages like Bootstrap, pixels are used in a max-width or min-width capacity, if used otherwise it's no longer fluid.

Comment: @Christina I wondered the same. drive by down-votes, gotta love 'em